# eval() alternative to get output of the string like "(0 AND 1 OR 1)"

Tags: php, string, eval

I have logical expression data from the database in string format -

```
"(id1 OR id2) AND (id3 OR id3)"
```

This can be any type of combination as it is a dynamic string based on user input.
After getting this from DB, I replace all Ids value by 0/1 based on some logic and this sting becomes -

```
"(1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 1)"
```

Now I want to run this string as PHP code and expect its output as a Boolean. But the problem is I used `eval()` PHP function which is not good for security reasons.

```
$op = "(1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 1)";
$op = eval('return '.$op.';');
```

And the only reason, I had to use eval is string type. If I run this `echo (1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 1)` then I get the expected output.

So can someone help me with this? What can be a better way for this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this other than `eval()`. You need to write code that parses it and evaluates it.

Comment: The [Symfony Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) component should be able to handle this without any further manipulation, if you can pull in a third-party package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Singular format

If it's always in the same format you could use a regex and format your own expression...

```
if(preg_match("/\((\d) OR (\d)\) AND \((\d) OR (\d)\)/", $string, $matches))
    var_dump( ($matches[1] || $matches[2]) && ($matches[3] || $matches[4]));
```

### Multiple format

**Warning** The below doesn't catch every expression if it isn't correctly formatted. For example the expression:

```
AND 1
```

Would result in a failure for both methods... You could get around this in regex by defining additional matching rules, for example:

```
Pattern         Replacement

/^\s*AND\s*1/   0
/^\s*AND\s*0/   0
/^\s*OR\s*0/    0

/^\s*OR\s*1/    1
```

But to cover everything would mean a long list of rules.

**Example expressions**

```
$expressions  = [
    "1 AND 0",
    "1 AND 1",
    "0 OR 0",
    "0 OR 1",
    "1 OR 1",
    "0 AND (1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 0) OR 0",
    "(1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 1)",
    "(1 AND 0 OR 1 ) OR (0 OR 1 OR 1) AND 1",
    "(1 OR 0) DELETE EVERYTHING!"
];
```

**Method 1: `eval`**

While people tend to hate on the use of `eval` (because it *potentially* allows the execution of rogue code) there's no reason not to use it so long as you sanitize your inputs.

So lets make a simple function:

```
function cleanBooleanExpression($string){                
    $string = preg_replace("/OR/i", "O", $string);       // Replace instances of OR with the letter O; i flag makes it case insensitive
    $string = preg_replace("/AND/i", "A", $string);      // Replace instances of AND with the letter A; i flag makes it case insensitive
    $string = preg_replace("/[^OA01() ]/", "", $string);  // Strip all non-legal characters
    $string = preg_replace("/O/", "OR", $string);         // Re-instate OR
    $string = preg_replace("/A/", "AND", $string);        // Re-instate AND
    return $string;                                       // Return the updated string
}
```

You can then use the sanitized output in `eval`:

```
foreach($expressions as $input){
    $input = cleanBooleanExpression($input);
    eval("var_dump({$input});");
}

/* Output:

bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)

*/
```

**Method 2: custom function**

Alternatively, if you really don't want to use `eval`, you could use regular expressions to evaluate the input:

```
function evalBooleanString($string){
    $string = preg_replace('/
        (
        \(1\)|
        [01]*1[01]+|
        [01]+1[01]*|
        \(*\s*1\s*OR\s*[01]\s*\)*|
        \(*\s*[01]\s*OR\s*1\s*\)*|
        \(*\s*1\s*AND\s*1\s*\)*
        )
        /x', 1, $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/
        (
        \(\)|
        \(0\)|
        00+|
        \(*\s*0\s*OR\s*0\s*\)*|
        \(*\s*[01]\s*AND\s*0\s*\)*|
        \(*\s*0\s*AND\s*[01]\s*\)*
        )
        /x', 0, $string);

    $string = trim($string);

    if($string === "1" || $string === "0"){
        return (bool)$string;
    }
    return evalBooleanString($string);
}
```

And use it like:

```
foreach($expressions as $input){
    $input = cleanBooleanExpression($input);
    var_dump(evalBooleanString($input));
}

/* Output:

bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)

*/
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not always in the same format, It can any combination like "(1 AND 0 OR 1  ) OR (0 OR 1 OR 1) AND 1"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help

```
function tmp_function($body)
{
    $tmp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "tmp_func");
    file_put_contents($tmp_file, "<?php return function() { return $body };");
    $function = include($tmp_file);
    unlink($tmp_file);

    return $function;
}

$op = "(1 OR 1) AND (0 OR 1);";
$call_me = tmp_function($op);
var_dump($call_me());
```